# unbiased estimator for bernoulli variance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ IID  from a Bernoulli distribution while $n>2$.

If I want to find an unbiased estimator for $$(1-p)p$$ as a function of $X_1, X_2$ and the use  [Rao Blackwell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem)

I realize this is the $\mathbb{E}[Var(P)]$  not sure if this implies anything instantly.

My question is what is the pmf  for bernouli here to get the unbiased estimator?

What I thought of so far:

$\theta  = p(1-p)$

$\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}] = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}T(i)(1-p)^ip^i = p(1-p)$

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Define $N=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and try computing things like $E[N]$ and $E[N^2]$ to see how you can put these together.